# NSString stringWithFormat with tabs instead of spaces

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

You can see that I add 40 spaces after my string but it starts at index 0.
Can I do the same thing with tab "\t" instead of spaces " "?

```
NSString *firstString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringToWrite] stringByPaddingToLength:40 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes `@"\t"` will put tab instead of spaces.
Also, your line could be a bit more simple :

```
NSString *firstString = [stringToWrite stringByPaddingToLength:40
                                                    withString:@" "
                                               startingAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: what is the use of the string ?

Comment: i want to create two columns where first word start at 0 and second words are all aligned

Comment: i tried this out and the function works as expected : it append tabs at the end of the string.

Comment: yes, `NSString *s1 = @"toto"; NSString *s2 = [s1 stringByPaddingToLength:30 withString:@"\t" startingAtIndex:0]; NSLog(@">>%@<<", s1); NSLog(@">>%@<<", s2);`

Comment: but remember each `\t` is considered as one char.

Comment: ok but when I have my firstString with stringByPaddingToLength, I want to join firstString with another string, is it possible?

Comment: yes, get another one using `stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", first, second`.

Comment: no, it don't work fine; in NSLog I have a correct text formatted but when I print I haven't a text formatted well...