# Change the tab (\t) length when using stringWithFormat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stringwithformat, tabstop

I would like to specify a tab length or tab stops when using `\t` in the function stringWithFormat:

```
buttonText3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"D:\t%ld:%02ld" , hoursAndMinutesDay.hours,hoursAndMinutesDay.minutes];
```

I have already tried to use a backspace after the tab but this does not work:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"D:\t%c%ld:%02ld", 0x0008, hoursAndMinutesDay.hours,hoursAndMinutesDay.minutes];
```

Using a number of spaces instead `\t` is not an option since the text before `\t` has different widths depending on the characters.

Comment: What are you doing with the string after you create it (what renders it to the screen)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699930/how-can-i-use-the-t-tab-operator-to-format-a-nsstring-in-columns and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860633/nsstring-stringwithformat-with-tabs-instead-of-spaces

Comment: @iPatel He said spaces won't work for him though.

Comment: @Wain: I want to display it in an UITextLabel.

Comment: You can always get the length of the string before and decide how many spaces to add...

Comment: @Wain: The individual characters have different widths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not. Display of tab characters is outside of NSString's control.

If you are using Cocoa API such as UITextView to display the string, you may be able to use NSAttributedString and NSParagraphStyle to set tab stops for display.